# Interpretation of $S^1$

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that $(0,\infty)/\sim$ with $x\sim y$ if there exists integer $n$ such that $\frac{x}{y}=2^n$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$. I have proved the relation is an equivalence relation, but I have difficulty to find map from $(0,\infty)$ to $S^1$ that is constant on each equivalence class.

Comment: Take logarithms. Are you familiar with the identification $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \cong S^1$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan yes. Thank you for the idea, that's very neat!

Comment: @LaurencePW Then you should officially answer your own question.